# Did the death of Thomas Chatterton influence Romanticism?

Tags: history-of-literature, thomas-chatterton

The beginning of the 19th century is known as the Romantic period. While I know that Chatterton wasn't the *first* romantic, would it be plausible to say that Chatterton's death gave *ignition* to Romanticism?

If not, then what exactly quite ignited the Romantic period? I am aware that the Romantic period was a reaction to the age of Enlightenment, but who or what exactly gave that burst?

Comment: Why could it not be a confluence of factors?  With a vague beginning, even?

Comment: Well I seldom observed that to be the case throughout history. Usually every event has to have a main reason.

Comment: Actually, in my observations, there is usually a confluence even when it appears, at first, to be a main reason.

Comment: Oh, well that's interesting. Then how exactly did the death of Chatterton effect the movement?